# .htaccess rewriting to different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this is simple and Ive seen it answered several other places, all of which seem to indicate that what I've tried is correct.

I want to proxy `/api/foo/bar` to `https://www.example.com/foo/bar`.
The rule I have which is not being matched is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "/api/(.*)$" "https://www.example.com/$1" [P]
```

Note:  I only have access to .htaccess, so I can't use `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassReverse`

Comment: Use RequestHeader, Header is for respond headers

Comment: OK.  The rewrite rule still isn't triggering though.  Edited the question to remove this bit since the rewrite rule is the primary concern.

Comment: Try removing the leading slash

Comment: removing the trailing slash results in a 404 error when hitting `api/foo/bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this? Edit your **.htaccess** file and use the code bellow:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/foo/bar$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

**UPDATE:**

As per apache documentation you cannot use ProxyPass directives in **.htaccess** so it has to be configured within the virtual host in apache.

However, you can use a **ProxyPassReverse** to internally rewrite the **Location** field of proxied requests that cause a redirect. You'll just need to use **mod_rewrite**'s P flag to proxy instead of **ProxyPass**.

So try adding the code bellow in your **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```

Check and see if that works better!

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  I'm not sure 301 is appropriate though since it's not a redirect and links shouldn't be updated.  I'm just circumventing cross domain issues by trying to proxy mydomain.com to yourdomain.com. 
 More standard access control stuff isn't possible in this situation.

Comment: This worked except I had to add the wildcard back for the backreference to mean something:  `RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`.  I tried replacing `R=301` with `P` and it gives a 500 error...  any idea?  I'd prefer to proxy it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try and see if the new rules are better for your intended use

Comment: This is the first thing I tried.. i referenced that in my question (not being able to use proxypass). When I use the P flag, I get a 500 error. I wonder if this is indicating that mod_proxy is disabled?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up with a definitive answer:  yes, using `[P]` I get a 500 error (I don't have access to see exactly what the error is though).  I suspect the host disallows proxy rules?  `RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,P]` . I'll just use 301... close enough for my needs.

Comment: I'm glad if it works somehow. Sorry that it's not working the exact way you wanted...